# laser_filter LaserScanRangeFilter is only using NaN as replacement value

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laser-filters, rosandroid, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED see answers

I want to use a laser_filter to limit my ranges to certain values.
But after defining the thresholds it replaces them only with NaN Values instead of my defined replacement values.
Those are my parameters:

```
scan_filter_chain:
- name: range
  type: LaserScanRangeFilter
  params:
    use_message_range_limits: false
    lower_threshold: 4.0
    upper_threshold: 5.0
    lower_replacement_value: 4.1
    upper_replacement_value: 4.9
```

But instead of replacing the values outside of the threshold it sets them to NaN...
[image: image description]

Any ideas? I feel like i am making some basic mistake.

Ok i realized the ndk crosscompile uses version: laser_filters-release-release-indigo-laser_filters-1.7.3-0.
I will try to update to 1.8.6 and try again. Lets see if this fixes something

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306523/laser_filter-laserscanrangefilter-is-only-using-nan-as-replacement-value/) by [manster2209](https://answers.ros.org/users/35175/manster2209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the problem was that the laser_filters package only supports replacement values for the ScanRangeFilter from version 1.8.5 and the ndk crosscompile had version 1.7.3.
To update one can replace the version number of laser_filters in the ndk.rosinstall file of the crosscompilation.
For it to compile one needs to update the version of the base package filters as well.

```
-    version: filters-release-release-indigo-filters-1.7.4-0
+    version: filters-release-release-indigo-filters-1.7.5-0
-    version: laser_filters-release-release-indigo-laser_filters-1.7.3-0
+    version: laser_filters-release-release-indigo-laser_filters-1.8.5-0
```

---

Originally posted by [manster2209](https://answers.ros.org/users/35175/manster2209/) with karma: 20 on 2018-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0